# iPhone 5s 16GB iOS11 randomly restarts

Tags: iphone, crash, restart

I think it has to do with iOS 11.
I have tried updating to latest 11.2.1, but it did not help, also tried backup, reset, and restore did not help.
Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT 12/21:

- I should mention that I took it the Apple store, and they did not find any issues. They recommended backup, erase and restore.
- Also take a look as this user suggest the issue is iOS 11 - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8101649
- I downloaded app that show battery capacity status - it is 1400/1570mAh 89%, this means its not a battery issue.

EDIT 12/25:

- Went again to apple store to ask to try replace battery and see if that help. They did full test again, and said it seem like software issue, all hardware is in great condition. And they recommended reset without restore. We did full reset and I did not install any apps, and the issue is still not resolved.

EDIT 1/18/2018:

- I bought a new battery from iFixit. It did not resolve the issue. I did notice that switching to low battery mode does help reduce the random shutdowns, but not completely resolve it. I guess my solution is switch to android device.

I believe that if apple would allow switch back to iOS 10.3.3 , then that would probably have resolved it. I assumed the latest iOS would be better, but probably not for older models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: installed iOS 12 beta, phone worked for short while, and is now a brick. My colleague have the exact same model, he did not upgrade beyond 10.3.3 and his phone is still working fine.**

I believe this is a bug with apple software, and that they do not care much if the software support older models. Here is the message from apple showing no support for model 5s:

> Preventing unexpected shutdowns
>
> About a year ago in iOS 10.2.1, we delivered a software update that
>   improves power management during peak workloads to avoid unexpected
>   shutdowns on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, and
>   iPhone SE. With the update, iOS dynamically manages the maximum
>   performance of some system components when needed to prevent a
>   shutdown. While these changes may go unnoticed, in some cases users
>   may experience longer launch times for apps and other reductions in
>   performance.
>
> Customer response to iOS 10.2.1 was positive, as it successfully
>   reduced the occurrence of unexpected shutdowns. We recently extended
>   the same support for iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus in iOS 11.2.
>
> Of course, when a chemically aged battery is replaced with a new one,
>   iPhone performance returns to normal when operated in standard
>   conditions.

I also tried replacing the battery via iFixit, it did not help at all.

References:

http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/12/29/ifixit-matches-apples-29-battery-swap-cost-covers-pre-iphone-6-devices

https://www.apple.com/iphone-battery-and-performance/

Answer (score 3):

Your issue could be one of two things: the battery or an issue with your OS.

You said you have already had your battery tested, but battery apps aren't very accurate and different tests at the Apple store will show different results.

Start by calling (or chatting with) Apple support. Do this on a different device. Ask if they can remotely run a Mobile Resource Inspector test. This will test many different components in your phone and is how they diagnosed my battery issue.

If they determine it is not a battery issue, do a **FULL** restore. You'll need a computer with iTunes for this.

> As always, make sure all of your data is saved. You will not restore from a backup, so save it another way.

Start by putting your phone in [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263).

- Shut down your iPhone.
- Press and hold both the Home and Top buttons until the connect to iTunes screen appears.
- Connect to iTunes.

iTunes will show a popup asking if you'd like to restore or update. You'd like to **Restore**.

[image: Recovery mode popup]

Your computer will download a completely new copy of iOS 11 - that's what makes this different than doing this on an iPhone.

If your computer takes longer than 15 minutes to download the update, you'll need to put your phone in recovery mode again. Press and hold the Home and Top buttons at the same time to do this.

> **Warning:** Restoring your phone this way will require your Apple ID password unless you didn't have Find My iPhone enabled. If you do not remember your Apple ID password, you should reset it at [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com)

If none of this fixed your phone, I'd recommend talking to Apple Support about your issue over the phone. (Over-the-phone support is generally faster than live chat)

Comment: Thank you, full reset did not help. I called support, and they said its a hardware issue. Will take to apple store to see if they can fix it.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to contact Apple Support by phone and inform them of the issues you're having. Describe to them the process you went through of backing up, erasing, and restoring multiple times. Inform them of the Apple Store full diagnostic that said the hardware was functional.

Like you said, doing a full software reset (without restore) should have eliminated all software issues. This means that there could be a possible hardware issue with your phone that isn't being detected by their systems yet, similar to the [recent issue with iPhone 6s batteries](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/).

If this ends up being the case, they may send you a replacement phone at no charge.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely your battery causing this issue. Your battery capacity deteriorates over time. You might want to consider replacing your battery. It will resolve this issue, speed your iPhone, and prolong its life. It is very common to have this issue with iPhone 5s.

Comment: Thank you, but I took it to apple store, and they did a test and found no issues.

Comment: maybe try setting your phone as completely new iPhone by erasing everything. do not back it up from the last backup. maybe some software wasn't installed properly and is causing this issue. you will lose all your data though

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac computer, you can download the coconutBattery app and test the battery yourself. I did that and it indicated my battery was not charging all the way. Download the app to your computer and then connect your phone via cable. Then run the app.

Also, go to settings/battery on your iPhone and see if it gives you a message about your battery.

The Apple store is probably right but it doesn't hurt to monitor your battery yourself.

Comment: Thank you, replacing battery did not help.

Answer (score 0):

When you backed up, erased and restored did you restore your backup? If so then thats the issue. Some of your data in that backup is corrupted.

Try to restore with iTunes and then set up the iPhone as new this time and see if it still restarts again. It shouldn't, but if it does then you need to contact Apple support for further support.